# How to differ between self.message_post() and raise osv.except_osv()

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I have been working on developing an OpenERP module. I am understanding things regarding OpenERP development using Python language. I am a little bit confused on how to differ in between self.message_post() and  raise osv.except_osv(). Can someone give me a little know-how understanding to this.

```
Hopes for suggestion
  Best wishes
  Thanks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.message_post` does as the name suggests, posts a message.  `osv.except_osv` is a python exception, albeit a special one.

Raising an `osv.except_osv` does a couple of things:

1. Interrupts the current processing (it is a python exception after all).
2. Causes OpenERP to roll back the current database transaction.
3. Causes OpenERP to display a dialog box to the user rather than dumping a stack trace and giving the user a "bad stuff happened" message.

The common way to raise them is...

```
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _

raise osv.except_osv(_('This is the error title'), _('This is the error message'))
```

Comment: There's a typo here:

    from openero.tools.translate import _

is

    from openerp.tools.translate import _